# Is Tbilisi a good place to tour after this year's flood?

Tags: georgia-country, tbilisi, natural-disasters

I'm going to Georgia within few weeks and I wonder how Tbilisi looks like now. Is it devastated after the flood which took place almost a month ago?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I'm not in Tbilisi myself, my wife and children are at present in Georgia, having been in Tbilisi during the flood and the following week, although they now went to the summer house in the mountains.  I have been speaking with them almost daily - so this is almost a first person account.

Severe flooding did occur a couple of weeks ago in Tbilisi, resulting in both human and animal deaths and many injuries and physical losses.  The long-term effect of it though isn't that great, from what I understand.

The only long term "damage" as far as the tourism is concerned is the zoo.  It was all but wiped out by the floods.  It's not open to the public at present.  Other than that, the city continues operating just as it did before. There's water, electricity and gas; telephone network and internet are fine; public transport runs fine; all shops, restaurants, etc. are open; museums are open according to their normal summer opening hours.  Public paths along Kura are open, however parts of them are rather wet from rains that took place over the last week or so.

Naturally, the aftermath is still visible in Mziuri park and the Heroes Square, as well as throughout the city, but all these places are open to the public.

So, all in all, it's still a great place to visit.  I myself will be flying there at the end of July - but I have family there, so floods or no floods, I'd have to go.

If you're interested in any specific venue or place, it should be easy to find that out.

Comment: Hope your family made it ok, some pictures give a pretty grim impression of the city :-/

Comment: @Blackbird57 Thanks. Yes, they made it ok.  They live higher up in the cit, the water didn't make it anywhere near them.  They didn't loose electricity and, apart from some pretty serious amount of rain, didn't really feel anything too much out of the ordinary.

Comment: I live in Tbilisi and can confirm that this answer is very accurate. Life is back to normal.